# Login in java using text file

Tags: java

Hi I am using a text file to check the login names 
 I have code like this

```
    <%
       String username= request.getParameter("username");     

    BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/name.txt"));  
    String ln="";  
    int lnnum=0;  

    while((ln=b.readLine())!=null)  
    {  

    lnnum++; 

    if(username.equals(ln))  
    {     
          response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

    } else

        response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp"); 

    }


    %>
```

but getting the error like this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:473)
org.apache.jsp.LoginCheck_jsp._jspService(LoginCheck_jsp.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: I suggest you do this work in servlet instead of doing that is jsp.

Comment: One thing is, you should put `response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp"); ` behind your `while` loop, otherwise you are only checking the first line from your text file

Comment: Also if you doing what I am think you doing, which is access control using txt file.. perhaps you would like to look at Java Authentication and Authorisation Services and some Realms like JDBC Realms or something!

Comment: Your login will be very unsecure if success is based just on redirect to target page

Comment: You cannot redirect inside the JSP because the servlet container render your JSP file in the response. You have to do this inside a `Servlet` or yout can include your needed JSP (e.g. `<%@include file="Error.jsp" %>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `sendRedirect` method twice in the same place, also use `requestDispatcher` to forward to another resource within your application.

For Example:

```
while((ln=b.readLine())!=null)  
{  

    lnnum++; 

    if(username.equals(ln))  
    {     
        request.getRequestDispatcher("resourcePath/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}

request.getRequestDispatcher("resourcePath/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

if the while loop fail to send user to the index page, then send him him to the error page.,

Comment: thanks for the replay.. still it's not redirecting to the error page